# Trans application with Netbeans

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, ide, twig

I want to do translations in your project, so I need to add tags {% trans %} and {% endtrans %}. How can I in Netbeans select the text to translate and automatically (click or keyboard shortcut) to add these tags? I use Symfony with Twig. I can use also other IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [netbeans symfony plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40565/php-symfony2-framework). 
Btw, for translations in twig, you can use this type of syntax:

```
{{ 'your.translation'|trans }}
```